# Transforming UV through Geometrying Nodes

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

I'm trying out the UV Unwrap node, and I've got it working - but the orientation of the UV is unpredictable, so I'm hoping there's a way to transform it to the direction/scale that I want.

In the image below - you can see that a value for the X scale of 3.3 has the UV aligned one way, but a value of 3.4 has the UV aligned the other way. I want to make sure that the alignment is consistent.

[image]
[image]

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: You could read a value from the UV, calculate an angle based on it, and reverse rotation of that angle. This will work to align a particular part of the unwrap, but it doesn't guarantee the UV stays aligned in general: it's not a numerically stable process and can bifurcate.

Comment: Just checking: Does the answer below help you, or do you still have questions about it?

Comment: I haven't had the opportunity to incorporate this into my project, but it appears to work well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this particular case, you don't actually need to use the `UV Unwrap` node.

Instead, it is actually sufficient to put the UVs together yourself:

[image]

The procedure here is as follows:

1. Create a *Bounding Box* from your mesh.
   [image]
2. Separate *Min* and *Max* and get the lowest and highest values for the X- and Y-axis respectively, so that you get a constant aspect ratio of these two axes.
   [image]
3. Then use `Map Range` and map the positions into the range $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$.
   [image]
4. Finally, use `Vector Rotate` to rotate your UVs around the Z-axis and align them exactly the way you want.
   [image]

This way you can use any scaling and also align the UVs individually, and the size always adjusts to the longest side.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>